# IBM Worklight version 8.0 - Forbidden Error while accessing token

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, worklight-server

Receiving below error while accessing token:

```
WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
    .then(
        function (accessToken) {
            console.log(accessToken);
            console.log("Connected to MobileFirst Server")
            WL.Logger.debug("Connected to MobileFirst Server");
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log("Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server");
            WL.Logger.debug("Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server");
        }
    );
```

Response:

```
errorCode: "403"
errorMsg: "Forbidden"
responseHeaders: {connection: '[Keep-Alive]', content-length: '[199]', content-type: '[text/html; charset=iso-8859-1]', date: '[Thu, 21 Apr 2022 07:29:35 GMT]', keep-alive: '[timeout=120, max=1840]', …}
responseText: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>403 Forbidden</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Forbidden</h1>\n<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>\n</body></html>\n"
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
```

Details:
IBM Worklight platform version: '8.0.0.00-20190910-142437'

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a custom HTML response and not from IBM MobileFirst.
Add more details - what request resulted in this error message? Do you have an intermediate entity ( webserver/firewall/load balancer etc) in the topology?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code to access the token.

Note: I'm receiving this error after I have overwritten the new APK with a older version . If I directly install the APK, there is no issue observed.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are getting an HTML response indicating the 403 and this happens when the apk is replaced, points to a possible network policy or webserver blocking a PUT request to

```
http://<host>:<port>/mfp/api/registration/v1/self/<clientid>
```

The reasons why this could be the cause are:

1. MFP server does not respond with HTML. MFP server responds only with JSON. The response seen in your case is a custom HTML.
2. When you install an apk fresh and connect to the server, the request that fires is `POST http://<host>:<port>/mfp/api/registration/v1/self`, while a `PUT http://<host>:<port>/mfp/api/registration/v1/self/<clientid>` fires when the apk is updated (or overwritten).

The other remote possibility is, you have application authenticity protection enabled in the server that is not working in case of the older apk. However, the chances of this being the case is near zero, as the error message returned gives a clear indication of the issue and it would not have worked in case of a fresh install too.

I would suggest you verify if your network policy does not allow PUT requests.